# Linear Algebra: Linear transformation and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hi could some one please help. I am having problems proving this.

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries and let $f (t) =\det(A - tI)$ be its characteristic polynomial.
>
> Prove that $f(A) = 0$.

Thank you!!

Comment: It's called the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. Search this website, I'm sure you'll find where it has been answered before. See, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362156/linear-algebra-characteristic-polynomial?

Comment: Don't, however, arrive at $f(A) = det(A-AI) = det(0) = 0$.